# How do invoke a message box with a listbox item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

[image: Windows Form App]

I'm working on an application that has the user fill out the four fields on the left and click the "Add Car" button and the Model, Color, and Year would appear as an listbox item and once they select that listbox item a messagebox would appear giving the user the price they wrote in the price field earlier. I've got everything to work except having the messagebox appear when I click on the listbox item. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Here I've included my code for this project. I used Visual Studio 2017 and the type of project is a Visual C# Windows Form App project if that helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MIS_312_Extra_Challenge_Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string model, color, details = "", AllDetails = "", models = "";
        int year;
        double price;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_addCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model = txtModel.Text;
        color = txtColor.Text;
        year = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text);
        price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);

        details = model + " " + color + " " + year + Environment.NewLine;
        AllDetails = AllDetails + price + " " + Environment.NewLine;
        models = models + model + " " + Environment.NewLine;

        list_carDetails.Items.Add(details);
        txtModel.Clear();
        txtColor.Clear();
        txtYear.Clear();
        txtPrice.Clear();
        txtModel.Clear();

    }

    private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void list_carDetails_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void list_carDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] all = AllDetails.Split();
        string[] m = models.Split();
        string[] modelName = { };
        int i;
        foreach (var car in list_carDetails.SelectedItems)
        {
            string details = car.ToString();
            modelName = details.Split();
        }

        for(i=0;i<m.Length;i++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(modelName[0],m[i])== 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The price of the " + modelName[0] + " is $" + all[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you placed the "MessageBox.Show()" portion to the first line of list_carDetails_SelectedIndexChanged()? If so, did it work then?

Comment: Also, have you tried breakpointing at the for loop to see if it ever reaches the MessageBox?

Comment: I have tested your code. It works fine. You can check if "list_carDetails" subscribed to the event "SelectedIndexChanged". Try to use `list_carDetails.SelectedIndexChanged += list_carDetails_SelectedIndexChanged;` in `Form1()`.

Comment: @KyleWang that worked, thank you very much!